# Distorted output

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdf, graphs

I have a problem with my `tex` code. I am trying to create a line diagram, but right now the output is distorted and not scaled properly. Does anyone have an idea how to fix that? This is my code:

```
\documentclass[mnsc,blindrev]{informs3} 

\begin{document} 

\tikzset{axis line style/.style={thin, gray, -stealth}}
\newcommand*{\TickSize}{2pt}%

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [<->] (0,5) node[left, font=\itshape] -- (0,0) -- (5,0) node[below, font=\itshape]{Project phase};
\draw [thick, dash dot] (2,26.9) -- (3,23.1) -- (4,19.2) -- (5,15.3) node[right]{FG};
\draw [thick, dashed] (2,24.6) -- (3,22.4) -- (4,20.1) -- (5,17.8) node[right]{FN};
\draw [thick] (2,25.9) -- (3,26.7) -- (4,27.5) -- (5,28.3) node[right]{TG};
\draw [thick, dotted] (2,25.9) -- (3,26.8) -- (4,27.6) -- (5,28.4) node[right]{TN};


\foreach \x in {1,...,4} {%     
    \draw ($(\x,0) + (0,-\TickSize)$) -- ($(\x,0) + (0,\TickSize)$); 
}

\foreach \y in {1,...,4} {%     
    \draw ($(0,\y) + (-\TickSize,0)$) -- ($(0,\y) + (\TickSize,0)$); 
}

\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The end result should look like this sketch,exept that I need the new values and numbers on the y-axis.

[image]

Thank you guys!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Also it would be nice if you could add an image of your current result. Then we, the helpers, already have an impression what your code looks like and could imagine what the result *should* look like ...

Comment: Thank you Stefan, I updated my post, as you suggested.

Comment: A node should have a possible empty text. So, `node[left, font=\itshape]{}` in the first node. But, why using empty node there?

Comment: What do you mean by *distorted and not scaled properly*? You are simply drawing lines connecting points (dahed and dotted). Too simple to be wrong. Please, explain better.

Comment: To remove the overlapping on `TN` and `TG`, simply change the position of nodes, that is, use `above` for `TN` and maybe `below right` for `TG`.

Comment: Stil this is not an MWE, because you missed to load the `tikz` package and for that it also has to be loaded the `calc` library to work. And as Sigur already has mentioned, even then the code is not compilable, because you missed to give a text to the first node. From the provided image I guess this should be `Completed workload`.

Comment: Besides that I totaly agree to Sigur, that the output corresponds to your input, i.e. you draw an axis system in the coordinates 0 to 5, but the lines you draw have y-components of minimum 15. That is, why the lines are drawn so much higher than the axis lines. Since you (still) didn't provide a sketch or something similar that shows the expected result, there is no-one who is able to help you ...

Comment: thanks Stefan, I added a sketch, maybe its clear now what Iam trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for that. Now I am sure that everything of importance is already written in the previous comments to solve your issues. That are i) add curly braces (with some text) after `node left,font=\itshape]` and ii) you need to state propper coordinates to draw the lines at the places you want them to have, e.g. for "FG" it should look similar to `\draw [dash dot] (0,3.5) -- (5,0.5) node {FG};`.